# FileSystemWatcher not working with Unit test

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

i try this simple test to work with [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) Class
but the OnFileChanged event not firing

```
    [Test]
    public void CanNotifyWhenFileChanged()
    {

        var watcher = new XMLWatcher(_path);
        watcher.StartWatching();
        AddXMLNodeTofile(_path);// change the file
        bool c = watcher.IsFileChanged;
        Assert.IsTrue(c);

    }
```

and this is my Method

```
public void StartWatching()
{
    var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
                      {
                          Path =
                             Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
                          IncludeSubdirectories = false,
                          NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess |
                                         NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
                                         NotifyFilters.FileName |
                                         NotifyFilters.DirectoryName,
                          Filter = FilePath
                      };

    watcher.Changed += OnFileChanged;
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `_path` and `GetExecutingAssembly().Location` are ending up similar enough that the FSW should invoke an event?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever please add your comment as answer :)

Comment: Ganesh R.'s answer covers the same ground

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that some Unit Test runners (NUnit, MSTest) do shadow copying of files i.e. the test binaries are copied to a separate location before execution. Hence the _path and the path where your test assembly reside may not be the same.

Also make sure that _path and the folder you are watching are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Your test is probably completing before the event is fired. I use a library called [FluentAssertions](http://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentAssertions/) for testing events.

Comment: If what Tim is saying is true, try wrapping your assert in a SpinWait. SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => myPredicate(), 10000)

Comment: Actually NUnit has delayed assertions `Assert.That(c, Is.True.After(delayInMilliseconds));`